# Get clicked element value angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm new on angularjs. I wrote a code on jquery. But I want to write on angularjs. I want to get clicked element value and data-id. Later I want to insert an input value gotten value. I can get data-id but I cant get button value. I want to convert all jquery to angular. How can I solve?

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-md" id="emlk_d">
    <button type="button" data-switch-set="size" data-switch-value="normal" ng-click="emlk_d_change($event);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-id="2" ng-model="k_1">K_1</button>
    <button type="button" data-switch-set="size" data-switch-value="normal" ng-click="emlk_d_change($event);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-id="1">S_1/button>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#emlk_d button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary').siblings().removeClass('btn-primary');
        var x=$(this).text();
        $('.d_ak').text(x);
        var x=$(this).attr("data-id");
        if(x==2){
            $("#emlk_d2").val(x);                     
        }else if(x==1){                      
            $("#emlk_d2").val(x);
        }                                                                       
    });
```

**Angular JS**

```
    var app = angular.module("main_app", []);
    app.controller("main_cont", function($scope) {
        $scope.emlk_d_change = function(e) {
            var id = $(e.target).data('id');
            alert(id);
            var x=angular.element('[data-id="'+id+'"]').val();
            alert(x);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ng-click method

```
$scope.emlk_d_change = function(event){

var button = event.currentTarget;
console.log(angular.element(button).attr('data-id')); // get the data-id values
console.log(angular.element(button).text()); // button content
}
```

Comment: $ is not defined your code is not working I removed jquery.js

Comment: it must has angular.element(button).attr('data-id'); İn this case it is working.